# dropdown list display base on a radio button

Tags: asp.net

I am an amature programmer. I have just start coding around one month

I am trying to write a code which shows the specific values of a database table in a dropdown list based on the radio button checked changed.

I tried to do it by using a session which saves the id of the table values and sends it to the drop down list, but nothing happens

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="rdbHome" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                    GroupName="rdb" oncheckedchanged="rdbHome_CheckedChanged" />

<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
                    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="p" DataValueField="playerID">
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:BasketballConnectionString %>" 
                    SelectCommand="PlayerName" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:SessionParameter Name="team1ID" SessionField="team1" Type="Int32" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

---

```
protected void rdbHome_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string conStr = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BasketballConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("team1ID", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mID", int.Parse(Request.QueryString["mID"]));

        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("matchTeam2", con);
        cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mID", int.Parse(Request.QueryString["mID"]));




        try
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader;
            reader = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
            //reader2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
            reader.Read();
            Session["team1"] = reader["team1ID"].ToString();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@team1ID", Session["team1"]);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            lblMsg.Text = "خطا" + ex.Message;
        }

    }
```

---

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[team1ID](@mID INT)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT teamTbl.teamID AS team1ID from 
teamTbl join matchTbl ON matchTbl.team1ID=teamTbl.teamID
WHERE matchID=@mID
END
```

---

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[matchTeam2](@mID int)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT t1.teamName as team1Name,t2.teamName as team2name,matchTbl.playeName,matchTbl.playerScore,
matchTbl.team1Score,matchTbl.team2Score,team1ID,team2ID
FROM matchTbl JOIN teamTbl as t1 on matchTbl.team1ID=t1.teamID
JOIN teamTbl as t2 on matchTbl.team2ID=t2.teamID
WHERE matchTbl.matchID=@mID


 END
```

---

and the code for sqlDataSource

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PlayerName](@team1ID INT)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT playersTbl.playerName, playersTbl.playerID
FROM teamTbl JOIN playersTbl ON teamTbl.teamID=playersTbl.teamID
WHERE teamTbl.teamID=@team1ID
END
```

Comment: is it doing the post back trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your help guys, the code worked fine, there were only some silly mistakes in it, the above code is edited and has no problems

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not populating the dropdown at all in this case. Inside 'rdbHome_CheckedChanged' method, you should be populating the 'DropDownList1' dropdown control.

Something like the following:

```
DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("5", "5%"));
```

Comment: i think i have populated it in sql data source, but i forgot to mention it in my post, i have updated it already, I'll be thank you if you take a look at the code again

Comment: actually the teamID is sent to drop down list using session and the playerName sp will return the playerName and the dropdown list must show the player names